# Can Sony Vegas Pro run in Wine?

Tags: 14.04, wine

I'm not very familiar with Wine, and my Windows installation screwed up. So basically, I want to use Sony Vegas Pro, and I'm out of a Windows operating system. Is it possible to get Vegas Pro to run in Wine?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/552609/how-to-install-sony-vegas-pro-in-ubuntu-14-10

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if you have 8GB of RAM or more then you can just download windows 10 from MS for free and run it in virtualbox. You can integrate it so well Vegas will just be another window on your Ubuntu desktop. Use samba to share the relevant folders with your Windows VM, and share the C:\ drive in the VM with Ubuntu, and you can do anything you need to in the Windows directories right from bash and nautilus.

Comment: The OP is asking whether they can run Sony Vegas through WINE; VM is another alternative, although the OP might not be aware of it.

Comment: I am aware of VMs, but I just thought that WINE woud be faster than VMs.